# Uncaught ReferenceError: submit_ajax is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

Killing myself here about this error.  The function is definitely defined.  Chrome keeps saying that it's not.

Stripped down HTML...

```
<form class="form-signup" id="create_student">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left">
            <label for="username">Student Username*</label>
            <br>
            <div style="display: block">
                <input class="form-control popover_onfocus" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (!$form_valid && !empty($_POST)){ echo $username;} ?>" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Your student can login with this or his/her email address if you provide one.  Have this be betwen <?=$settings->min_un?> and <?=$settings->max_un?> characters please." required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: left">
            <label for="contact_info">Student's Email (Optional)</label>
            <br>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control popover_onfocus" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Student's Email" value="<?php if (!$form_valid && !empty($_POST)){ echo $email;} ?>" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="This is optional, but if your student has an email, he/she can login with this and also get important emails that are relevant to them for a course, tutoring, etc.">
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>    
</div>


<button onclick="submit_ajax()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="next_button" style="font-size: 24px" disabled="disabled">Create Student Account</button>
```

Stripped down Javascript...

```
//For submitting form data via AJAX
$(document).ready(function(){
    function submit_ajax(){
        data = {'username':$('#username').val(),'password':$('#password').val(),'confirm':$('#confirm').val(),'fname':$('#fname').val(),'lname':$('#lname').val(),'email':$('#email').val()}

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo AJAX_DIR; ?>/create_student_account.php',
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                //AJAX success
                $('#success_fail_icon').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign lom_big_success_icon"></span>');
                $('#success_fail_message').html('Success! Student account created for ' + data['fname'] + '.');
            },
            error: function() {
                //Ajax failure
                $('#success_fail_icon').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign lom_big_fail_icon"></span>');
                $('#success_fail_message').html('Uh oh! Something went wrong.  Please try again, or contact us for assistance.');
            }
        });     
    }
});
```

Clearly, the function IS defined.  I have no idea why this isn't working.  I'd appreciate any assistance.

Note: I know that the `data` variable has more form elements than are shown.  I'm trying to display a stripped down version of my problem instead of the whole thing to make this post not so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `submit_ajax` inside another function. it won't be accessible outside it. Just remove `$(document).ready(...` since it's unnecessary in this case, then you should be good.